# grab all observations from a data set that are present in a second data set based on a linker ID using %in% function R

Tags: r

So, say I have two data sets:

```
d1<- data.frame(seq(1:10),rnorm(10))
colnames(d1) <- c('id','x1')

d2<- data.frame(seq(3:7),rnorm(5))
colnames(d2) <- c('id','x2')
```

Now, say I want a new dataset, `d3`, that is the data from `d1` with values of `id` that are also present in `d2`. I'd like to use a really simple function, something like:

```
d3 <- d1[id %in% d2$id]
```

Except this is printing an error for me. What is a simple one liner to accomplish this?

Comment: so many down votes! no comments!

Comment: Perhaps the reason for down votes is that there must be so many answers to this type of question.

Comment: @user3949008 was going through them and couldn't find as simple and readable of a line of code as I wanted. Also, the fix you posted above doesn't seem to work. Apparently it is necessary to specify `d1` both inside and outside the brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use

```
 subset(d1, id %in% d2$id)
```

Or

```
 d1[d1$id %in% d2$id,]
```

---

Not sure if this simplifies, but a `data.table` solution may be more efficient.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(d1, key='id')[d2$id]
```

Comment: this second line is exactly what I am looking for. Anyone that further simplifies it in the next 12 minutes can take the answer!